# What is the technical error if we declare a Deque as a general one which allows input and output from both sides?

Tags: data-structures

We know that a Deque has two sub category...
Input restricted and output restricted...
Now what is the technical error in designing a Deque in such a way that it has no restrictions 
i.e. The user can enter and remove data from both the front and back at any time ...with any restrictions !!!

Comment: Standard implementations, like Java ArrayDeque or C++ std::deque, have no such restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under [Distinctions and sub-types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue#Distinctions_and_sub-types), the Wikipedia article says, "This general data class has some possible sub-types:" It then goes on to list the input- and output-restricted. Note that they are *possible* sub-types. Nothing in the article or any other literature I've seen says that you can't have an unrestricted deque, and in fact many runtime libraries provide such.

So there is a deque (unrestricted double-ended queue), and there are input-restricted and output-restricted deques.

It's perhaps a bit of a stretch, but one could make the argument that both FIFO queues and LIFO stacks are also deque sub-types. The FIFO queue is input-restricted at one end and output-restricted at the other. A LIFO stack is input- and output-restricted at the same end.